# deploy flask app with heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, flask

I started following the `heroku` tutorial for deploying a flask app found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python).

I followed everything precisely and to the point. I could deploy on my local server and I could also deploy the app when after I did `heroku run bash`.

Unfortunately, when I try deploying with heroku open, I get this following error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-tundra-8811.herokuapp.com fwd=67.212.10.54 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I don't get any other following errors in my error log, only this appears after running heroku open.

Thanks

Comment: Heroku open *will* open your app in your default browser. It seems that something else is misconfigured.. when you did foreman start in your computer could you see the *"hello world"* message in localhost?

Comment: Yeah, when I tried foreman start my application loaded locally

Comment: and when you do **heroku ps** you see a process running? reading some of the heroku error codes it seems that your app has crashed [Here are the error codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed), so you have to revisit the tutorial steps by step and see what you are missing.